# Remove Hash from array based on key in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm new to Ruby. This is my array containing multiple hash. Now, I want to remove all Hash whose ':total_duration' is 0. This is what I've tried, but nothing is happening.

```
@array = 
[{:tid=>"p121709", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>0},
{:tid=>"p121710", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>0},
{:tid=>"m121459", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>713}]
```

```
@op_arr.delete_if { |key, total_duration| [key].include? 0 }
```

The output should be

```
@array = [{:tid=>"m121459", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>713}]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `[{:tid=>"m121459", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>713}]`

Comment: @AlokSwain yes. You're correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements of the array are hashes, so you need to treat them as hashes:

```
@array.delete_if{|h| h[:total_duration] == 0}
# => [{:tid=>"m121459", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>713}]
@array
#=> [{:tid=>"m121459", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>713}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@array = [{:tid=>"p121709", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>0},
{:tid=>"p121710", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>0},
{:tid=>"m121459", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>713}]

@array.reject!{|e| e[:total_duration].zero?}
```

P.S - I think the output you need is `[{:tid=>"m121459", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>713}]` `@array` has one element which is a `Hash` and not what is posted in the question i.e. `[{{:tid=>"m121459", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>713}}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
@array.delete_if{|x| x[:total_duration] == 0}
```

this will solve your problem

Comment: To date appear to have four identical answers. The first two were given within seconds of each other, so I can't object to having both. Having more, given minutes later, such as yours, serve no purpose.  You may not have not noticed the others before posting but that is no matter. That is the reason for my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@array = [
    {:tid=>"p121709", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>0},
    {:tid=>"p121710", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>0},
    {:tid=>"m121459", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>713}]

    @array.delete_if{|e| e[:total_duration]== 0}
    # => [{:tid=>"m121459", :uid=>"S2G1", :total_duration=>713}]
```

Hope this will help for you.

Comment: To date appear to have four identical answers. The first two were given within seconds of each other, so I can't object to having both. Having more, such as yours, given 16 minutes after the first, serve no purpose. That is the reason for my downvote.